# Find shortest distance in between nodes in following graph

Tags: c++, graph

A graph is defined as such, that graph has N nodes, where each node is assigned a number 1 <= k <= N to it (each number is assigned only to one node). An edge exists between nodes `i` and `j`, if `i` is biggest divisible of `j` (`i` != `j`). Given two nodes I need to find shortest path between them.

I thought its easy question. I thought all I need to do is just replace given two numbers with their biggest divisible until they are equal, and simply print out number of times I substituted a number with its divisible. However I fail all tests (however my code passes the example tests).

Here is code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>  

using namespace std;

int biggest_divisor (int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= ceil (sqrt(number)) + 1; i++){
        if (number% i == 0){
            return number/ i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int N, a, b;
    int a_steps = 0;
    int b_steps = 0;

    cin >> N >> a >> b;

    while (a != b){
        if (a > b){
            a = biggest_divisor (a);
            a_steps += 1;
        } 
        if (a < b) {
            b = biggest_divisor (b);
            b_steps += 1;
        }
    }
    cout << a_steps + b_steps;
}
```

Comment: fyi: biggest_divisor returns the smallest divisor

Comment: @bolov No. It finds smallest divisor, and then returns original number divided by the smallest divisor, thus returning biggest divisor.

Comment: don't do that when there is an equally simple way of doing it the obvious way. It only adds confusion.

Comment: what's the input for the example that works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete Solution:

```
int biggest_divisor (int number) {
    for (int i = number / 2 ; i >= 1; i--){
        if (number% i == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int N, a, b;
    int steps = 0;

    cin >> N >> a >> b;

    while (a != b) {
        (a > b) ? a = biggest_divisor (a) : b = biggest_divisor (b);
        steps++;
    }
    cout << steps;
}
```